# Insert an X and Y into a MySQL database that does not already exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic database table for a grid

```
CREATE TABLE `grid` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customers_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seen` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I'm trying to get an x and y value from the grid that doesn't already exist in the grid. (with means to use it as part of an insert later) I'm using the following but, sometimes, it returns a set of coordinates that do already exist...

PHP

```
private $_maxColumns    = 144;
private $_maxRows       = 90;
```

MySQL (Within quotes in PHP - hence the curly brackets around the variables)

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR( (RAND() * ( {$this->_maxColumns} - 1 + 1 ) ) + 1 ),
        '-',
        FLOOR( (RAND() * ( {$this->_maxRows} - 1 + 1 ) ) + 1 )
    ) as 'random'

    FROM `grid`

    WHERE 'random' NOT IN (
        SELECT CONCAT( `x`, '-', `y` ) FROM `grid`
    )
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: if you did all the maths outside the query, you could write a much simpler one. that would end up being a simple select with a single `where !=`

Comment: I suggest to random x and y in PHP and check if that value exist in table with a SELECT. Repeat what in a do-while() until that value is not in table.

Comment: @WilliamPerron Any underlying reason why you would suggest that? Most (if not all) databases are perfectly capable of checking the values before insert. @Mike, you could either use `IF NOT EXIST()`, `NOT IN` or perform a `LEFT JOIN` where where a value that does not exists equals `NULL`

Comment: @Xorifelse Because, IMO, it's simpler to implement like that and more readable than all in a query. But yes, it's maybe less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns existing values because you got the filter completely wrong:

```
WHERE 'random' NOT IN (
    SELECT CONCAT( `x`, '-', `y` ) FROM `grid`
```

In the where criteria you compare the string literal `'random'` to subquery that will never ever return this value. In the where clause you cannot filter on a calculated field because the select list is evaluated after the where clause. You can only filter on such fields in the having clause and remove the speechmarks around the word random:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    FLOOR( (RAND() * ( {$this->_maxColumns} - 1 + 1 ) ) + 1 ),
    '-',
    FLOOR( (RAND() * ( {$this->_maxRows} - 1 + 1 ) ) + 1 )
) as random

FROM `grid`

HAVING random NOT IN (
    SELECT CONCAT( `x`, '-', `y` ) FROM `grid`
)
```

However, it is possible that the above query will not return any rows at all. I would rather generate a list of non-existing coordinates within a range and randomly choose one of them. I would have a helper table with all possible x - y pairs, just do a left join on the grid table with is null in the where criteria and either use `order by rand() limit 1`, or do the random selection from php.